# Floating Neutal on Generator

Tags: generator

I have a floating neutral on the generator that powers a sub-panel. Can the 110v outlets still be used to power other items such as saws, refrigerators? Or can the generator be configured to have a floating neutral on the 220v outlet and still have a bonded neutral on the 110v side? Thank you.

Comment: Make/model of generator?

Comment: When you're powering "other items", is the generator plugged into the house?

Comment: Yes it is plugged into the house.

Comment: Generic Model 1646-3